# Haskell: GHCi script versus direct entry

Tags: haskell

Working through Hutton's new text, I encountered strange behavior in ghci.  When I load the function altmap from a text file, it behaves correctly; however typing the same two lines directly into ghci gives the error shown below:

```
*Main Lib> altmap f g [] = []

*Main Lib> altmap f g (x:y:xs) = (f x):(g y):(altmap f g xs)

*Main Lib> altmap (2*) (3*) [1,2,3,4,5,6]

[2,6,6,12,10,18*** Exception: interactive:2:1-49: Non-exhaustive patterns in function altmap
```

While I'm at it, can someone explain the difference between "Prelude" and "Main Lib" ? I'm using the rc2 release of ghc 8.0.2

Comment: Note that you had to use `let ... = ...` in GHCi prior to version 8.

Answer (score 0):

The later definition of `altmap` overrides the older one. Therefore, you really only have one pattern defined.

Basically, you did this:

```
ghci> x = 5
ghci> x = 42
ghci> print x
42
```

You either need to define both in the same line or use multi-lines:

```
*Main Lib> altmap f g [] = []; altmap f g (x:y:xs) = f x : g y : atmap f g xs
```

Note that `altmap f g xs` can also be written as `zipWith ($) (cycle [f,g]) xs`.

For your additional question: the modules before the `>` are the ones you have currently imported. So you have imported `Main` (with all symbols) and `Lib`. Have a look at the GHC documentation for more information.

Comment: Hm. Now that I found the duplicate, should I delete my answer?